# How to detect which strings in a list contain words from a list of keywords in R

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

Very new to R and hoping for help.

I have a list of 1000 product names, and I have a list of 80 key words or phrases. I need to determine how many of the 1000 product names contain one or more of those key words or phrases.

Example: if one of the 1000+ product names was "honey bunches of oats" and one of the 80+ keywords is "honey", I need it to show up as TRUE in a new column next to "honey bunches of oats"

Uploaded both lists as csv files. I made a vector for each list, and tried to use the following:

```
str_detect(products, regex(".keywords.", ignore_case = TRUE))
```

This came back with all false results. I also tried to use `grepl(keywords, products)` which returned zero results as well.

I am confident there should be instances where the keywords are contained within these strings. Is it looking for exact matches? I need it to show partial matches.

Comment: Please share a small reproducible example of your data.

Comment: @deschen 2 examples of products: "36262722 - ABC CAJUN SALT 7373 H" and "737171 - CARIBBEAN SALT+25#ABCD" 2 examples of keywords "CAJUN" and "CARIBBEAN SALT"

Comment: Not as a comment, but as real code objects in your question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
products <- c('apple hello', 'banana', 'peach', 'a')
.keywords. <- c('apple', 'each')

library(stringr)
str_detect(products, paste0(.keywords., collapse = '|'))

# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```